# How to add a credit card logo in the product page of a Shopify site

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Reviewing our Shopify site, I realized that a major difficulty with Shopify is that it's as if the theme does everything possible to obfuscate credit card usage. The site is replete with all sorts of references to Google Pay, Amazon Pay, etc., but credit card payments are always difficult to find.

I would like to know how to add a credit card logo right below the BUY IT NOW button. Could you please let me know if it is possible to do it in Shopify by editing LIQUID file? If so, please point me

[image]

Comment: Which theme are you using ? It should be some section named product.liquid or something (depends on theme) that renders this part of the page. You should be able to add the image there.

Comment: Thanks, theme is Prestige. I was already thinking of the liquid file that you just mentioned.

Comment: @BilalAkbar, thanks Bilal, I got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Its possible to do in shopify by editing Liquid file.

You can find code of "Buy It Now" button in your template.

```
{% if enable_dynamic_buttons %}
{{ form | payment_button }}
{% endif %}
```

Either code is in sections/product-template.liquid or in snippets/product-form.liquid

You can add code of logo after above code. You can upload logo image either in theme or under files in shopify and then can use HTML code to put logo image.

For e.g.

```
<img src="{{'creditcardlogo.png' | file_img_url: 'original' }}">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: The code found in product-form.liquid is   `{%- if section.settings.show_payment_button and product.template_suffix != 'pre-order' -%}
    {{ form | payment_button }}
<!--TrustedSite Code-->
<br>
<div class="trustedsite-trustmark" data-type="1001"></div>`

Comment: The image I need to display is uploaded using files section and the file name is 4Cards300.jpg

Comment: Could you please add the HTML to display this image below Button to your answer, and I will insert that into my product-form.liquid file directly on the site?

Comment: I tried adding the line `<img src="{{'4Cards300.jpg': 'original' }}">` but the site then didn't even open after that. When code was removed, the site came back. Is the way of adding the code wrong here?

Comment: Thanks, I made it work. It was something too simple.\